# SQLite não retorna filtro com data específica (codificação no Flutter)

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, sqlite3

Estou tentando realizar um filtro por uma data específica, mas o retorno é sempre 0.
A tabela do DB foi criada assim:

```
CREATE TABLE refrigeracao (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    id_servidor INTEGER, 
    id_empresa INTEGER, 
    id_pdv INTEGER, 
    id_usr INTEGER, 
    avaliacao INTEGER, 
    mensagem TEXT, 
    tipo_salvamento INTEGER, 
    data DATETIME, 
    salvo INTEGER
)
```

Inseri 7 registros na tabela e funcionou normal. No campo data foi salvo datas como este exemplo: `2024-01-16 21:01:43`

Porém, quando executo o seguinte código abaixo, passando na função a data '2024-01-16', ele retorna zero.
Segue função:

```flutter
getExecucoesRefrigeracaoPorData3(String dataBusca) async {
    Database db = await DBHelper.instance.database;
    int resultado = 0;
    resultado = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM refrigeracao WHERE strftime('%y-%m-%d', data) = ?;",[dataBusca]))!;
    return resultado;
  }
```

**OBS**: quando retiro a cláusula `WHERE` do *SQL*, a função retorna `7` (quantidade exata que está salva no DB).